# How to return multiple values with the method array.from and new set

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I would like to know if it is possible from an array of objects to retrieve several unique values with the method array.from new set.

For example :

```html
   this.data = [
  {
    "_id": "5bf57b965401169dd81c2a51",
    "age": 35,
    "name": "Paige Zamora",
    "gender": "female",
    "company": "AUTOMON",
    "reference_id": "12"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5bf57b96c2c3b88adff4b972",
    "age": 40,
    "name": "Jennifer Carr",
    "gender": "female",
    "company": "SYNKGEN",
    "reference_id": "11"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5bf57b969dd839926db78767",
    "age": 38,
    "name": "Weaver Rosales",
    "gender": "male",
    "company": "ETERNIS",
    "reference_id": "10"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5bf57b968c845ea691e76c84",
    "age": 31,
    "name": "Myers Pickett",
    "gender": "male",
    "company": "ETERNIS",
    "reference_id": "10"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5bf57b96998c44eff083d3fa",
    "age": 36,
    "name": "Dona Nicholson",
    "gender": "female",
    "company": "ETERNIS",
    "reference_id": "10"
  }
]
```

I would like to retrieve the following unique values: **reference_id** and the **company** associated with the reference_id, which would give this:

```
[{12, AUTOMON}, {11, SYNKGEN}, {10, ETERNIS}]
```

I thought I would use this method:

```
const list = Array.from (new Set (this.data.map ({reference_id}) => reference_id)));
```

what returns :

```
[12,11,10]
```

I do not know if this method can be used to return multiple values like the list above ?

Comment: `{12, AUTOMON}` doesn't make sense. If those are keys, what are the values? If that's supposed to be an array, you use `[...]`, not `{...}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also group them in a `Map` (ignoring any repetitions and where keys are the string representations of `reference_id` and `company`) and return an array from its values:

```js
var data = [{
    "_id": "5bf57b965401169dd81c2a51",
    "age": 35,
    "name": "Paige Zamora",
    "gender": "female",
    "company": "AUTOMON",
    "reference_id": "12"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5bf57b96c2c3b88adff4b972",
    "age": 40,
    "name": "Jennifer Carr",
    "gender": "female",
    "company": "SYNKGEN",
    "reference_id": "11"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5bf57b969dd839926db78767",
    "age": 38,
    "name": "Weaver Rosales",
    "gender": "male",
    "company": "ETERNIS",
    "reference_id": "10"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5bf57b968c845ea691e76c84",
    "age": 31,
    "name": "Myers Pickett",
    "gender": "male",
    "company": "ETERNIS",
    "reference_id": "10"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5bf57b96998c44eff083d3fa",
    "age": 36,
    "name": "Dona Nicholson",
    "gender": "female",
    "company": "ETERNIS",
    "reference_id": "10"
  }
];


var res = Array.from(data.reduce((acc, {reference_id, company}) => {
  acc.set(`${reference_id},${company}`, {reference_id, company});
  return acc;
}, new Map()).values());

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks @slider for you reply.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [JSON](http://json.org/) with the wanted data and take then the parsed values as result.

Why a string instead of an object, you may ask. The problem here is every new object with the wanted properties is a new object, and not the same.

[`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) works wite a single primitive or object and checks, if an object's reference is the same. By taking a string, the value could be checked and you get unique strings in the set. This required to convert the JSON back to an object.

```js
var data = [{ _id: "5bf57b965401169dd81c2a51", age: 35, name: "Paige Zamora", gender: "female", company: "AUTOMON", reference_id: "12" }, { _id: "5bf57b96c2c3b88adff4b972", age: 40, name: "Jennifer Carr", gender: "female", company: "SYNKGEN", reference_id: "11" }, { _id: "5bf57b969dd839926db78767", age: 38, name: "Weaver Rosales", gender: "male", company: "ETERNIS", reference_id: "10" }, { _id: "5bf57b968c845ea691e76c84", age: 31, name: "Myers Pickett", gender: "male", company: "ETERNIS", reference_id: "10" }, { _id: "5bf57b96998c44eff083d3fa", age: 36, name: "Dona Nicholson", gender: "female", company: "ETERNIS", reference_id: "10" }],
    unique = Array.from(
        new Set(
            data.map(({ reference_id, company }) =>
                JSON.stringify({ reference_id, company }))
        ),
        json => JSON.parse(json)
    );
    
console.log(unique);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This really is a thing of beauty

Comment: Thanks @Nina Scholz for you reply.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
this.data.map((el) =>{ return {age: el.age, company: el.company} })

// You get this array
//0: {age: 35, company: "AUTOMON"}
//1: {age: 40, company: "SYNKGEN"}
//2: {age: 38, company: "ETERNIS"}
//3: {age: 31, company: "ETERNIS"}
//4: {age: 36, company: "ETERNIS"}
```

> {12, AUTOMON} doesn't make sense, obj is { key: value, key: value...}